# Linked files and folders in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

In Windows Vista (not sure about other versions), I've noticed that Explorer may automatically link a file and a folder based on their names.

For example, if I go under Firefox, choose Save As, choose "Web Page, Complete", and save `page.htm`, then Firefox also creates a `page_files` folder containing stylesheets and images used by `page.htm`.

From this point forward, Explorer treats `page.htm` and `page_files` as linked.  Creating a copy of one also creates a copy of the other.  Deleting one automatically (without confirmation) deletes the other.  Renaming one, strangely enough, does not rename the other, but it does pop up a dire-sounding warning:

> If you rename this file, it will no longer belong to the folder 'page_files.'
>
> To rename it safely, open the file, save it with a new name, and then delete the folder 'page_files'.
>
> Do you want to rename the file anyway?

Is there any way to configure or disable this file-folder-linking behavior?  It's a nuisance to have Windows renaming or deleting files and folders without my telling it to, and the workaround of manually renaming one or the other then naming it back is tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Control Panel, and click 'Classic View' on the left sidebar.

Open 'Folder Options'

Click the 'View' tab and scroll down to 'Managing pairs of Web pages and folders'

Choose 'Show and manage the pair as a single file'
Now Explorer will only show `page.htm` and treat both the file and the folder as one file.

Or, choose 'Show both parts and manage them individually' and Explorer will treat them as plain old `page.htm` and `page_files`.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks.  Those options weren't available for me, so I used http://windowsxp.mvps.org/webpairs.htm to find the corresponding registry keys.

Answer (score 3):

Although this feature (called "Connected Files") may be considered a nuisance (especially if not expected), it can be useful in some contexts. It is documented by Microsoft here:[Managing the File System - Connected Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#connected)

(Thanks to Anders on StackExchange Aug 10 '17 at 17:57)